# Redirect URL by query string match?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a 301 redirect using `.htaccess` file to redirect:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?/knowledgebase/
```

To:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/knowledgebase/
```

Ive tried about 30 different redirect/rewrite suggestions but none work, can anyone provide the specific `.htaccess` setting I need please?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/knowledgebase/$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /knowledgebase/ [L,R=301]
```

Edit: When debuging htaccess rewrite rules I find [this](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) tool very useful

Comment: When redirecting to the same domain, you don't have to put the full domain on right hand of the RewriteRule and you don't need the `%{REQUEST_URI}` as you can use it directly from the RewriteRule in some specific cases you may need to use the request Uri but this isn't one of it.